# ModelState.IsValid ignoring [Required] attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

For some reason, the `ModelState.IsValid` check in my controller is returning true even though my entity and viewmodel property has a [Required] attribute on the field that is 0.

This is the entity:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int FareId { get; set; }
    public virtual Fare Fare { get; set; }
}
```

And the viewmodel that my view uses:

```
public class BaseTicketViewModel
{
    [Required, Display(Name = "Fare")]
    public int FareId { get; set; }
    public Fare Fare { get; set; }
}
```

In my view, I've used a number of radio buttons instead of a drop down list, something which may be a cause of the problem, I just don't know how:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FareId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @foreach (FareGroup fareGroup in Model.FareList)
        {
            <h5><strong>@fareGroup.Name</strong></h5>

            foreach (Fare fare in fareGroup.Fares)
            {
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.FareId, fare.Id)
                    @fare.Name
                </label>
            }
        }
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FareId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

When I submit the form without selecting a fare, my controller raises a `DbUpdateException` which tells me that the INSERT statement conflicted with a FOREIGN KEY constraint, basically that the `Fare` with ID 0 doesn't exist:

> {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Tickets_dbo.Fares_FareId". The conflict occurred in database
>   "redacted", table "dbo.Fares", column
>   'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

By my understanding, if the `FareId` property on the viewmodel/ticket entity is 0 then `ModelState.IsValid` should be false because of the `[Required]` annotation on that property?

Comment: Paste the code of your controller.

Comment: `0` is a valid int.  As an `int` can't be null, you'll always pass the `Required` test.  You want a `int?`, or a nullable int.

Comment: Well 0 is still a value. When it says Required is means it can't be Null.

Answer (score 7):

[Integers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx) will default to 0 since they are value types.  As a result, it is meeting the requirements of the Required attribute, although rather poorly for your scenario.

The [Required Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation states:

> The RequiredAttribute attribute specifies that when a field on a form
>   is validated, the field must contain a value. A validation exception
>   is raised if the property is null, contains an empty string (""), or
>   contains only white-space characters.

Since your int is not nullable and since it clearly cannot be an empty string, it passes the validation.

If you wanted to ensure that your Id is not the default value, you could use the Range attribute, although if you did have an Id of 0 this would cause you problems.

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue,
   ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}.")]
```

Finally, as Chris Peterson pointed out, if `FareId` is nullable, it will be able to properly utilize the Required attribute since it will default to null if a value isn't posted, triggering validation.

```
[Required]
public int? FareId { get; set; }
```

Comment: I trimmed down my entity/viewmodel for the purposes of this post and I also have another property called `TimetableId`, defined in the same way as `FareId` only this is represented by a dropdown list in the view. That *also* sends the value `0` when you don't select anything, yet `ModelState.IsValid` then works as I would expect (returns false when a `TimetableId == 0`). What's the difference?

Comment: @ChrisWhite There must be another scenario occurring with TimetableId but since you haven't posted any code concerning TimetableId it is impossible to tell you what the difference is.

Comment: Another option would be to use a nullable int with the required attribute.